# Don't start Android UI test from Android Studio on real device

Tags: android

1. UI Tests on Emulator - ok
2. Debug on real device - ok
3. UI Tests on real device - don't start with error:

java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[STARTED, CREATED, RESUMED, DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(ActivityScenario.java:338)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:272)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:195)
.....

@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
.....

ActivityScenario.launch(SplashActivity::class.java)

Comment: did you find an answer for this problem?

Comment: Got the same problem. Can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the "display pop-up windows while running in the background permission" or something similar to that.
It worked for me on a Redmi Note 8 device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Flyme (Meizu phones), you should allow run in background for .test app in Security app:
[Run in background allowed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0M0Z.png)